# Alternative ways to adjust volume without using SSML prosody tag

Tags: google-text-to-speech

I am a product manager at an ed-tech company and we are planning to integrate Cloud Text-to-Speech into our educational quiz website. The goal is to allow users (teachers) to create their own English vocabulary tests, and the students can listen to the pronunciation of the words generated by TTS while answering. The students are elementary school students learning English as a foreign language, so it is important for them to hear the pronunciation loud and clear.

In SSML, the prosody tag can be used to adjust the volume, but it also changes the quality of the pronunciation. For example, in the following case:

```
<speak>
   <s><prosody volume="+30dB">
       rabbit
   </prosody></s>
       rabbit
</speak>
```

You can hear that the final "t" sound has an unnaturally strong emphasis.

Our engineers suggested that we can control the volume through JavaScript, but it doesn't work on iOS Safari, which doesn't meet our product requirements. I would like to know if there are other ways to increase the default volume of Cloud Text-to-Speech?

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know how you generate the speech?

It’s possible to generate and play the text directly as speech.

One other option is to generate an MP3 file and afterwards play the MP3 file in an audio element

The volume from and audio element you can change easily ( e.g.  audio.volume = 0.2 in javascript)

An advantage from this method is you can play the speech again and again without extra cost and in an audio element you can go forward or backward

The time to generate an MP3 file is almost the same as play the TTS directly

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. 

The approach you mentioned (generating an MP3 file and subsequently playing the MP3 file in an audio element) is precisely the method we previously employed. 

However, this method is incompatible with iOS Safari, prompting us to seek alternative solutions for adjusting the volume without relying on JavaScript.